# Basic CSS - Following a DRY principal, how would I remove display:grid from my selectors?

Tags: css

I am only beginning CSS and HTML so this is definitely a beginner question here. Below is a snippet of my current work:

```
/* Setup */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* Makes like box model work like I'd expect */
}
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
/* Necessary Selectors */
#header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto;

    align-items: end;
}
.logo {
    font-family: 'Rampart One', cursive;
    font-size: x-large;
}
#header-img {
    height: 25px;
}
#nav-bar {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    column-gap: 25px;
}

/* Media Query to change display based on screen width */
@media (max-width: 500px){
    #nav-bar {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto);

        justify-items: center;
    }
    #header {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(auto-fill, auto);

        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that in almost every ID Selector, I have to add `display: grid`. I am using `grid` as my main display, so I would like to not retype this. I've tried putting it in `*` and `body` selector, but this doesn't work as I expected. `*` breaks the webpage, and my selectors don't appear to inherit the display from `body`. Is there a better way?

Comment: a Direct descendant  css selector is probably what you're looking for. `body > * {...`.
Or mark them with some classes in your html.
There's plenty [options](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/css-selectors-cheat-sheet/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 (recommended)**: Add a `class` to both `#header` and `#nav-bar`:

```html
  <header id="header" class="grid"></div>
  <nav id="nav-bar" class="grid" aria-label="main navigation"></nav>
```

And then access the `class` in the `CSS`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
}
```

**Option 2**: Use a comma to combine your `CSS` selectors:

```css
#header,
#nav-bar {
  display: grid;
}
```

Comment: That first option is so much nicer! Thank you!